Angular 18 error did not render in 30 seconds on consume apollo
i discovered an error using Angular 18 SSR trying to control error response from grapqhl-apollo, the server method return error after 30 seconds and from angular client with the observable i must only show loading or an error alert when i receive an error response, but the component not render and after 30 seconds shows error "Page / did not render in 30 seconds".
Component:
@Component({
selector: 'app-shop',
standalone: true,
imports: [SidebarMenuComponent, ProductCardComponent, ProductCardSkeletonComponent],
templateUrl: './shop.component.html',
styleUrl: './shop.component.css'
})
export default class ShopComponent implements OnInit{
//...

public productsPaginatedResp = signal<ProductPaginatedResponse>({
  loading: true,
  products: [],
  error: false,
  hasNextPage: false,
  hasPreviousPage: false,
  totalCount: 0
});


ngOnInit(): void {
 //se suscribe a los cambios en la url
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  if (!this.isNavigating) {
    const after = params['after'] ? atob(params['after']) : null;
    const before = params['before'] ? atob(params['before']) : null;
    this.updateProductsPaginated(after, before, false);
  } else {
    this.isNavigating = false;
  }
 });
}

updateProductsPaginated(after: string | null = null, before: string | null = null, 
updateUrl: boolean = true) {

this.productsPaginatedResp.update(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  loading: true,
  error: false
}));

let observable$;

if (after) {
  observable$ = this.productsService.getProductsPaginatedAfter(this.defaultItemsShow, after);
} else if (before) {
  observable$ = this.productsService.getProductsPaginatedBefore(this.defaultItemsShow, before);
} else {
  observable$ = this.productsService.getProductsPaginatedAfter(this.defaultItemsShow, null);
}

observable$.subscribe(
  (response: ProductPaginatedResponse) => {
    console.log(response, "resp");

    if (response.error) {
      this.showErrorMessage('An error occurred while fetching products');
      this.productsPaginatedResp.update(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        loading: false,
        error: true,
        products: []
      }));
    } else {

      this.productsPaginatedResp.set(response);

      // Evitar recarga infinita
      if (updateUrl) {
        this.updateUrlParams(before, after);
      }
    }
  },
  (error: any) => {
    console.error('Subscription error:', error);
    // Manejar cualquier error inesperado en la suscripción
    this.showErrorMessage('An unexpected error occurred');
    this.productsPaginatedResp.update(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      loading: false,
      error: true,
      products: []
    }));
  }
);
}
//...

The service:
export class ProductsService {
 private apollo = inject(Apollo);

 getProductsPaginatedAfter(quantity: number, after: string | null): Observable<ProductPaginatedResponse> {
 return this.apollo.watchQuery({
  query: GET_AFTER_PRODUCTS,
  variables: { first: quantity, after: after }
 }).valueChanges.pipe(
  map(({ data, errors }: any) => {
    if (errors && errors.length) {
      throw new Error(errors.map((err: any) => err.message).join(', '));
    }
    return {
      loading: false,
      products: data.productsPaginated?.nodes || [],
      hasNextPage: data.productsPaginated?.pageInfo.hasNextPage || false,
      hasPreviousPage: data.productsPaginated?.pageInfo.hasPreviousPage || false,
      startCursor: data.productsPaginated?.pageInfo.startCursor,
      endCursor: data.productsPaginated?.pageInfo.endCursor,
      totalCount: data.productsPaginated?.totalCount || 0,
      error: false
    } as ProductPaginatedResponse;
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    console.error('Holi GraphQL error:', error.message);
    return of({
      loading: false,
      products: [],
      hasNextPage: false,
      hasPreviousPage: false,
      startCursor: undefined,
      endCursor: undefined,
      totalCount: 0,
      error: true
    } as ProductPaginatedResponse);
  })
 );
}
}



Apollo likely keeps the application unstable because of an open websocket (or a long lasting setTimeout/setInterval).
To work around this you'll have to run your function outside the angular zone with
ngZone.runOutsideAngular() => { ... }


if i convert the entire application to zoneless could it works?

Yes, this is also a possibility.

Not works, i change the entire app to zoneless and the results is almost the same

You likely forgot to remove the zone.js polyfill.

yeah i remove it

i have this warning: Angular detected that hydration was enabled for an application that uses a custom or a noop Zone.js

The warning is expected, as zoneless + ssr is not officially supported.
